# Having difficulty updating Odometer/RaceCar class in race scenario

Tags: java, class, object

spoiler alert: I'm a noob at Java.

With that disclosure out of the way, I have a homework assignment (yup I understand answers will be limited) where I'm supposed to "race" a hard-coded array of `RaceCar` objects, and I need to find out how I can update the `Odometer`/`RaceCar` class in order to increment miles of each of the `raceCar` objects by their respective MPH.

I think I've got a handle on most of it, but there's one, maybe two sections tripping me up in what syntax I need to use in order to update the Odometer's miles. My hunches:

1. I probably didn't create the constructors or something on the Odometer/RaceCar class correctly in order for it to update the miles for each car (and I'm not sure how to do it correctly)
2. I'm not calling it the right way and/or have not implemented the math properly.

Please help me understand how/where I'm going wrong and suggestions/direction to proceed forward because I'm pretty stuck and I'm not sure what to search for in order correct my mistakes.

Note: `Odometer` class is a "has-a" relationship with `RaceCar` class.

I'm having issue making this particular section work:

```java
// Update the race car’s odometer for 1 hour of racing
double milesTraveled = raceCars[i].getSpeed();
Odometer increment = new Odometer();
increment.incrementMiles(milesTraveled);
```

My `Odometer` class looks like:

```java
class Odometer {
    private double miles;

    public Odometer() {
        this.miles = 0;
    }

    public double getMiles() {
        return miles;
    }

    public void incrementMiles(double milesTraveled) {
        miles += milesTraveled;
    }
}// end class Odometer
```

All of my code:

```java
/*
Tanya Howland
CS 1150 - Principles of Comp. Science @ UCCS
Section 001 (M/W) 
Due April 14th 2021 @ 11:05am  
Assignment #10
Assignment description: 
Create class object race car and fill an array with 6 race cars and their specified information. Race each of the cars in
the array, with their own respective stats, against each other print statements updating how long the race cars have been
racing and which one will win. Create a separate .txt file via code with data on the race.
 */
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class HowlandTanyaAssignment11 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create array for race cars:
        RaceCar[] raceCars = new RaceCar[6];

        // call on method to fill in race car information:
        createRaceCars(raceCars);

        // initialize variables to starting values for race:
        double minutesRaced = 0.00;
        int iteration = 1;
        boolean raceComplete = false;

        // Starting race prompt + stats:
        printRaceCars(raceCars, iteration);
        System.out.println("\nAll cars are ready - let the race begin in 5...4...3...2...1");

        while (!raceComplete) {
            minutesRaced += 15.00;
            // System.out.println("Number of minutes raced..." + minutesRaced);
            // each 4 iterations = 1 hour...
            if (iteration == 4 || iteration == 8 || iteration == 12 || iteration == 16 || iteration == 20) {
                for (int i = 0; i < raceCars.length; i++) { 

                    // Update the race car’s odometer for 1 hour of racing
                    double milesTraveled = raceCars[i].getSpeed();
                    Odometer increment = new Odometer();
                    increment.incrementMiles(milesTraveled);

                    if (raceCars[i].getOdometer().getMiles() == 500) {
                        raceComplete = true;
                    } // if
                } // for
            } // if
            iteration++;
        } // while
        printRaceCars(raceCars, iteration);
        System.out.println("The winner is: " + raceCars[findWinner(raceCars)].getDriver());
    }// end main

// Create the race cars for the simulation based on the assignment sheet table
    public static void createRaceCars(RaceCar[] raceCars) {
        // (Driver, carNumber, averageSpeed(in mph))...
        RaceCar raceCar1 = new RaceCar("Shrek", 18, 77);
        raceCars[0] = raceCar1;
        RaceCar raceCar2 = new RaceCar("Fiona", 8, 85);
        raceCars[1] = raceCar2;
        RaceCar raceCar3 = new RaceCar("Donkey", 17, 117);
        raceCars[2] = raceCar3;
        RaceCar raceCar4 = new RaceCar("Dragon", 42, 81);
        raceCars[3] = raceCar4;
        RaceCar raceCar5 = new RaceCar("Farquaad", 14, 109);
        raceCars[4] = raceCar5;
        RaceCar raceCar6 = new RaceCar("Pinnochio", 19, 75);
        raceCars[5] = raceCar6;
    }

// Print the details for each race car in the array 
    public static void printRaceCars(RaceCar[] raceCars, int iteration) {
        if (iteration == 1) {
            System.out.println("Race cars at start of race: ");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Race cars at end of race: ");
        }
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"
                + "Driver         Race Car            Average            Miles\n "
                + "              Number              Speed              Completed\n"
                + "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < raceCars.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%-15.15s%-20.20s%-20.20s%-20.20s%n", raceCars[i].getDriver(), raceCars[i].getCarNumber(),
                    raceCars[i].getSpeed(), raceCars[i].getOdometer().getMiles());
        }
    }

// Determines which race car has won the race (the one with the most miles)
//Returns the index in the array for that race car  
    public static int findWinner(RaceCar[] raceCars) {
        double winner = raceCars[0].getOdometer().getMiles();
        int winnerIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < raceCars.length; i++) {
            if (raceCars[i].getOdometer().getMiles() >= 500.00) {
                winner = raceCars[i].getOdometer().getMiles();
                winnerIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return winnerIndex;
    }

// Print the details for each car in the race cars array to a file
    public static void writeCarDetailsToFile(RaceCar[] raceCars) throws IOException {

        // Setup the file reference variable to refer to a text file.
        // Assignment11.txt is the file that will be created on your hard drive.
        File fileName = new File("Assignment11.txt");

        // Create the file that the race cars will be written to.
        // This means connect Assignment11.txt on your hard drive to the
        // variable resultsFile in the code.
        PrintWriter resultsFile = new PrintWriter(fileName);

        // Write the details for each car to the file
        resultsFile.println("Race Car Details");
        for (int i = 0; i < raceCars.length; i++) {
            resultsFile.println(raceCars[i].getCarNumber());
            resultsFile.println(raceCars[i].getDriver());
            resultsFile.println(raceCars[i].getOdometer().getMiles());
            resultsFile.println();
        }
        resultsFile.close();

        // Shows where the file is located on your hard drive
        // Locate the file in your CS1150 eclipse workspace on your hard drive.
        // Compare the file contents to what is in the code below.
        System.out.println("Find the file here " + fileName.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println();

    } // writeCarDetailsToFile
}// end class assignment11

class RaceCar {
    private String driver;
    private int carNumber;
    private double averageSpeed;
    private Odometer odometer;// "has-a" relationship --> double check for correct syntax

    public RaceCar(String driver, int carNumber, double averageSpeed) {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.carNumber = carNumber;
        this.averageSpeed = averageSpeed;
        odometer = new Odometer();
    }

    public String getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public double getSpeed() {
        return averageSpeed;
    }

    public int getCarNumber() {
        return carNumber;
    }

    public Odometer getOdometer() {
        return odometer;
    }
} // end class Racecar

class Odometer {
    private double miles;

    public Odometer() {
        this.miles = 0;
    }

    public double getMiles() {
        return miles;
    }

    public void incrementMiles(double milesTraveled) {
        miles += milesTraveled;
    }
}// end class Odometer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace these two lines

```java
Odometer increment = new Odometer();
increment.incrementMiles(milesTraveled);
```

with this line:

```java
raceCars[i].getOdometer().incrementMiles(milesTraveled);
```

You are creating a new `Odometer` object in each iteration of the `for` loop and this `Odometer` object has absolutely no connection to any `RaceCar`. Remember that each `RaceCar` has its own `Odometer` and that is the one you want to increment. So the `getOdometer()` method gives you access to a `RaceCar`'s `Odometer` and after you access the `RaceCar`'s `Odometer`, you can modify it (by calling method `increment`).

Since you aren't really changing each `RaceCar`'s `Odometer`, your `while` loop never terminates because the `if` condition that changes the value of `raceCompleted` is never true.

```java
if (raceCars[i].getOdometer().getMiles() == 500)
```

If you are using an IDE, you need to learn how to use its debugger to debug your code. Then you would see that each `RaceCar`'s `Odometer` remains at 0 (zero) all the time. Alternatively, you could print the value before the `if` statement, i.e.

```java
System.out.println(raceCars[i].getOdometer().getMiles());
if (raceCars[i].getOdometer().getMiles() == 500) {
```

Refer to [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

You also need to change that `if` condition because if none of the `RaceCar`s reach **exactly** 500 miles, your `while` loop will also not terminate. The condition should be:

```java
if (raceCars[i].getOdometer().getMiles() >= 500)
```

In other words once a `RaceCar`'s `Odometer` reaches or passes 500, terminate the race.

For the sake of completeness, here is your entire code, including the above changes.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class HowlandTanyaAssignment11 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create array for race cars:
        RaceCar[] raceCars = new RaceCar[6];

        // call on method to fill in race car information:
        createRaceCars(raceCars);

        // initialize variables to starting values for race:
        double minutesRaced = 0.00;
        int iteration = 1;
        boolean raceComplete = false;

        // Starting race prompt + stats:
        printRaceCars(raceCars, iteration);
        System.out.println("\nAll cars are ready - let the race begin in 5...4...3...2...1");

        while (!raceComplete) {
            minutesRaced += 15.00;
            // System.out.println("Number of minutes raced..." + minutesRaced);
            // each 4 iterations = 1 hour...
            if (iteration == 4 || iteration == 8 || iteration == 12 || iteration == 16 || iteration == 20) {
                for (int i = 0; i < raceCars.length; i++) { 

                    // Update the race car’s odometer for 1 hour of racing
                    double milesTraveled = raceCars[i].getSpeed();
//                    Odometer increment = new Odometer();
//                    increment.incrementMiles(milesTraveled);
                    
                    raceCars[i].getOdometer().incrementMiles(milesTraveled);

                    if (raceCars[i].getOdometer().getMiles() >= 500) {
                        raceComplete = true;
                    } // if
                } // for
            } // if
            iteration++;
        } // while
        printRaceCars(raceCars, iteration);
        System.out.println("The winner is: " + raceCars[findWinner(raceCars)].getDriver());
    }// end main

// Create the race cars for the simulation based on the assignment sheet table
    public static void createRaceCars(RaceCar[] raceCars) {
        // (Driver, carNumber, averageSpeed(in mph))...
        RaceCar raceCar1 = new RaceCar("Shrek", 18, 77);
        raceCars[0] = raceCar1;
        RaceCar raceCar2 = new RaceCar("Fiona", 8, 85);
        raceCars[1] = raceCar2;
        RaceCar raceCar3 = new RaceCar("Donkey", 17, 117);
        raceCars[2] = raceCar3;
        RaceCar raceCar4 = new RaceCar("Dragon", 42, 81);
        raceCars[3] = raceCar4;
        RaceCar raceCar5 = new RaceCar("Farquaad", 14, 109);
        raceCars[4] = raceCar5;
        RaceCar raceCar6 = new RaceCar("Pinnochio", 19, 75);
        raceCars[5] = raceCar6;
    }

// Print the details for each race car in the array 
    public static void printRaceCars(RaceCar[] raceCars, int iteration) {
        if (iteration == 1) {
            System.out.println("Race cars at start of race: ");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Race cars at end of race: ");
        }
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"
                + "Driver         Race Car            Average            Miles\n "
                + "              Number              Speed              Completed\n"
                + "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < raceCars.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%-15.15s%-20.20s%-20.20s%-20.20s%n", raceCars[i].getDriver(), raceCars[i].getCarNumber(),
                    raceCars[i].getSpeed(), raceCars[i].getOdometer().getMiles());
        }
    }

// Determines which race car has won the race (the one with the most miles)
//Returns the index in the array for that race car  
    public static int findWinner(RaceCar[] raceCars) {
        double winner = raceCars[0].getOdometer().getMiles();
        int winnerIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < raceCars.length; i++) {
            if (raceCars[i].getOdometer().getMiles() >= 500.00) {
                winner = raceCars[i].getOdometer().getMiles();
                winnerIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return winnerIndex;
    }

// Print the details for each car in the race cars array to a file
    public static void writeCarDetailsToFile(RaceCar[] raceCars) throws IOException {

        // Setup the file reference variable to refer to a text file.
        // Assignment11.txt is the file that will be created on your hard drive.
        File fileName = new File("Assignment11.txt");

        // Create the file that the race cars will be written to.
        // This means connect Assignment11.txt on your hard drive to the
        // variable resultsFile in the code.
        PrintWriter resultsFile = new PrintWriter(fileName);

        // Write the details for each car to the file
        resultsFile.println("Race Car Details");
        for (int i = 0; i < raceCars.length; i++) {
            resultsFile.println(raceCars[i].getCarNumber());
            resultsFile.println(raceCars[i].getDriver());
            resultsFile.println(raceCars[i].getOdometer().getMiles());
            resultsFile.println();
        }
        resultsFile.close();

        // Shows where the file is located on your hard drive
        // Locate the file in your CS1150 eclipse workspace on your hard drive.
        // Compare the file contents to what is in the code below.
        System.out.println("Find the file here " + fileName.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println();

    } // writeCarDetailsToFile
}// end class assignment11

class RaceCar {
    private String driver;
    private int carNumber;
    private double averageSpeed;
    private Odometer odometer;// "has-a" relationship --> double check for correct syntax

    public RaceCar(String driver, int carNumber, double averageSpeed) {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.carNumber = carNumber;
        this.averageSpeed = averageSpeed;
        odometer = new Odometer();
    }

    public String getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public double getSpeed() {
        return averageSpeed;
    }

    public int getCarNumber() {
        return carNumber;
    }

    public Odometer getOdometer() {
        return odometer;
    }
} // end class Racecar

class Odometer {
    private double miles;

    public Odometer() {
        this.miles = 0;
    }

    public double getMiles() {
        return miles;
    }

    public void incrementMiles(double milesTraveled) {
        miles += milesTraveled;
    }
}// end class Odometer
```

This is the output I get when I run the above code:

```
Race cars at start of race: 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Driver         Race Car            Average            Miles
               Number              Speed              Completed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Shrek          18                  77.0                0.0                 
Fiona          8                   85.0                0.0                 
Donkey         17                  117.0               0.0                 
Dragon         42                  81.0                0.0                 
Farquaad       14                  109.0               0.0                 
Pinnochio      19                  75.0                0.0                 

All cars are ready - let the race begin in 5...4...3...2...1
Race cars at end of race: 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Driver         Race Car            Average            Miles
               Number              Speed              Completed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Shrek          18                  77.0                385.0               
Fiona          8                   85.0                425.0               
Donkey         17                  117.0               585.0               
Dragon         42                  81.0                405.0               
Farquaad       14                  109.0               545.0               
Pinnochio      19                  75.0                375.0               
The winner is: Farquaad
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! That makes much more sense. However my code is still not working and it's definitely due to my own logic errors ie: enters into endless loop with minutes incrementing disregarding my other statements. It should exit the first while loop if enough miles add up to 500, thus completing the race. and printing out the winner.*** EDIT: I figured it out and it was such a silly fix... =_=;;

Comment: Got it- and yes you totally answered my question the first time- thank you! I simply had an extra logical error on top of not understanding how to call Odometer via RaceCar and increment the miles. I found it and it's corrected- should've been if (raceCars[i].getOdometer().getMiles() >= 500)

Comment: Nope- I need to learn how to use my debugger.

Comment: Sorry! I couldn't see your other comments until now.